# Reorganisation of data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose

I have this data frame:

```
> data
        Date Treatment Plate.1 Plate.2 Plate.3 Plate.4 Plate.5 Plate.6 Plate.7 Plate.8 
1 2014-10-15         2       1       0       2       5       2       0      11       6 
2 2014-11-12         2       3       2       3       0       0       3       2       1
3 2014-12-11         2       1       0       1       1       0       1       1       0 
4 2015-02-11         2       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0 
5 2015-03-09         2       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

I have been trying to reorganise it into this format:

```
> manually.created.dataframe
        Date Treatment Abundance
1 2014-10-15         2       1       
  2014-10-15         2       0
  2014-10-15         2       2
  2014-10-15         2       5
  2014-10-15         2       2
  2014-10-15         2       0
  2014-10-15         2       11
  2014-10-15         2       3
  2014-11-12         2       2
  2014-11-12         2       3
  2014-11-12         2       0
etc.
```

I have tried to implement a transpose function to no avail. Any help or advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Sorry, I should have been more clear. Abundance is the values from Plate.1, Plate. 2, Plate. 3 etc for each date value. I would like to place Plates 1-8 into one vertical column titled "Abundance", replicating the values for treatment and date in adjacent vertical columns.

Comment: What is abundance supposed to be measuring in this context? It seems like the function melt from the package reshape2 might be what you want, but I'm not sure what you want in the third column.

Comment: That's a pretty confusing data format. You'd want another column specifying plate number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `melt` function from the `reshape2` package:

```
melt(data, id.vars = c("Date", "Treatment"), value.name = "Abundance")
```

You will get an additional column named `variable` in your output dataset with the Plate name

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(reshape2)
x = melt(data,id = c("Date","Treatment"))
```

This contains more columns than you have in your desired solution, but I think you probably would want those columns anyway because that tells you which plate the value came from.

But if not you could do:

```
x = x[-3]
```